# Composable LazyColumn/Pager Scroll while zoomed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I need to create the pdf reader, I am sending images bitmap array to lazy compose view, it works fine when there is no zoom but with zoom  the issue I am facing is that while scrolling to bottom it became too slow to scroll.
Following is the code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ViewPager(
    list: List<Pair<ImageBitmap, List<Fields>>>,
    minScale: Float = 1f,
    maxScale: Float = 3f,
    scrollEnabled: MutableState<Boolean>,
    isRotation: Boolean = false
) {

    var targetScale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val scale = animateFloatAsState(targetValue = maxOf(minScale, minOf(maxScale, targetScale)))
    var rotationState by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidthPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { configuration.screenWidthDp.dp.toPx() }
    val screenHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { configuration.screenHeightDp.dp.toPx() }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    VerticalPager(
         modifier= Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
//            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            .fillMaxSize(1f)
            .background(color = Color.Blue)
            .combinedClickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = null,
                onClick = {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                },
                onDoubleClick = {
                    if (targetScale >= 2f) {
                        targetScale = 1f
                        offsetX = 1f
                        offsetY = 1f
                        scrollEnabled.value = true
                    } else targetScale = 3f
                }
            )
            .graphicsLayer {
                this.scaleX = scale.value
                this.scaleY = scale.value
                if (isRotation) {
                    rotationZ = rotationState
                }
                this.translationX = offsetX
                this.translationY = offsetY

                Log.e("Ramesh lazycolumn size", "${this.size.width} ${this.size.height}")
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                forEachGesture {
                    awaitPointerEventScope {
                        awaitFirstDown()
                        do {
                            val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                            val zoom = event.calculateZoom()
                            targetScale *= zoom
                            val offset = event.calculatePan()
                            if (targetScale <= 1) {
                                offsetX = 1f
                                offsetY = 1f
                                targetScale = 1f
                                scrollEnabled.value = true
                            } else {
                                offsetX += offset.x
                                // todo change
                                if (offsetY + offset.y < screenHeightPx && offsetY + offset.y > -screenHeightPx) {
                                    offsetY += offset.y
                                }
                                if (zoom > 1) {
                                    scrollEnabled.value = false
                                    rotationState += event.calculateRotation()
                                }
                                val imageWidth = screenWidthPx * scale.value

                                val borderReached =
                                    imageWidth - screenWidthPx - 2 * abs(offsetX)
                                scrollEnabled.value = borderReached <= 0
                                if (borderReached < 0) {
                                    offsetX =
                                        ((imageWidth - screenWidthPx) / 2f).withSign(offsetX)
                                    if (offset.x != 0f) offsetY -= offset.y
                                }
                            }
                            Log.e("Ramesh lazycolumn xy ", "$offsetX $offsetY")
                        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
                    }
                }
            },
        count = list.size,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        flingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior()
    ) { page ->
        val it = list[page]
        Page(
            pageContent = {
                PageContent(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    imagePainter = BitmapPainter(it.first),
                    fields = it.second
                )
            },
            fields = it.second,
            color = if (page % 2 == 0) Color.Yellow else Color.Cyan
        )
    }
}
```

I have used the `LazyColumn`, `Pager`, Scrollable column but still same issue.

```
@Composable
fun Page(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fields: List<Fields>,
    pageContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    color: Color
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
//        Modifier.fillMaxHeight().background(color)
//        .height(placeables[0].height)
    ) {
        Layout(
            content = pageContent
        ) { measurables, constraints ->
            val placeables = measurables.map { measurable -> measurable.measure(constraints) }

            Log.e(
                "Ramesh",
                "Placeable ${placeables[0].height} ${placeables[0].width} \nConstraints ${constraints.maxWidth}, ${constraints.maxHeight}"
            )
            val factor = placeables[0].height
            layout(
                width = constraints.maxWidth,
                height = placeables[0].height
            ) {
                placeables[0].place(0, 0, 0f)
                for (index in 1..placeables.lastIndex) {
                    val fieldValue = fields[index - 1]
                    val offset = IntOffset(fieldValue.x, fieldValue.y - 70)
                    placeables[index].placeRelative(offset, 0f)
//                    placeables[index].placeRelative(fieldValue.x, fieldValue.y, 0f)
//                    placeables[index].place(fieldValue.x, fieldValue.y - 120, 0f)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun PageContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fields: List<Fields>,
    imagePainter: Painter
) {
    Image(
        painter = imagePainter,
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        modifier = modifier
//            .onGloballyPositioned {
//                val position = it.positionInRoot()
//                Log.e("ramesh image coordinates", "x = ${position.x} y = ${position.y}")
//                Log.e("ramesh image size", "x = ${it.size.width} y = ${it.size.height}")
//            }
    )
//    fields.forEach {
//        InputField(it)
//    }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?
thanks